# Python, is it a way to select easily the vertices representing the shape of a mesh

Tags: python

.
Hi,

I would like to select the vertices representing the shape of the mesh, the orange line in the Object mode:

[image]

Is it a way to do it easily (Maybe with Python?)

Thanks for you help.

Maxime

Comment: How did you select it in the picture?

Comment: Nothing is selected in the picture. The visual orange line is shown by Blender when the mesh is selected in Object mode

Comment: Oh, that's right. I'm on my mobile right now so I can't give you details but look up Loop selection. You can easily select the outer loop ring of your mesh without any scripting

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly I was not able to do it